# Cisco process memory usage

Tags: cisco, process, snmp, memory-usage, mib

I am trying to monitor a Cisco process memory usage. This is what I get with the command line:

`show system internal processes memory | inc PID|ipfib`

`PID TTY      STAT     TIME MAJFLT  TRS   RSS    VSZ %MEM COMMAND`

`6069 ?        Ssl  00:14:01      0    0 169480 532812  1.0 /lc/isan/bin/ipfib`

I want to use my SNMP poller to get this information, so far I have only found 
1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.2.1.1 has all the process names, pid, process usage.

All I need is the memory usage, but I can't find it.